# How to disable this warning: Warning: Custom fonts not added in `pages/_document.js` will only load for a single page. This is discouraged

Tags: next.js, fonts

I recently designed a 404 page using a custom font and I am getting this warning.

> 22:9  Warning: Custom fonts not added in pages/_document.js will only load for a single page. This is discouraged. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-page-custom-font  @next/next/no-page-custom-font

I read the official documentation and it says this but doesn't give way to disable the warning.

> When Not To Use It:
> If you have a reason to only load a font for a particular page or don't care about font optimization, then you can disable this rule.

And putting the font on `_document.js` doesn't solve my problem since it uses dynamic font (can be chosen by admins from admin panel). I am using Next.js 14.x.x with pages route.